# 'Use of unresolved identifier 'rootViewController'' errors in identifying and loading view controllers in app delegate

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Reading **Learn Swift by Building Applications** by Emil Atanasov, I am attempting to write code in the App Delegate to start the app on the `TabbarViewController` if the user is already logged in (rather than the SignInViewController). However, despite writing two similar functions for the login screen and the main view controller (the same as within the book), I'm getting a multitude of errors on the function for loading the main view controller - openMainViewController()

> errors:
>   'Pattern matching in a condition requires the `case` keyword'
>   'Use of unresolved identifier `rootViewController`'

I've traced back the book, made sure the Identifiers match in the main storyboard (although `TabbarViewController` does not have a class, is this a normal?)

```
func openSignInScreen() {
    if let signInViewController = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as? SignInViewController {
        signInViewController.view.frame = (self.window?.rootViewController?.view.frame)!
        signInViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        //nice transition between views
        UIView.transition(with: window!, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.window?.rootViewController = signInViewController }, completion: { completed in //nothing to do here
        })
        }
    }
//continue.. now open main View Controller
func openMainViewController() {
    if let rootViewController() = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarViewController") {
            rootViewController().view.frame =  (self.window?.rootViewController?.view.frame)!
            rootViewController().view.layoutIfNeeded()
            //nice transition between views
            UIView.transition(with: window!, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController() }, completion: { completed in //maybe do something here
        })
    }
}
```

I expect as I have written the code the same as in the book, that there would not be any identification problems. However I'm getting a bunch of errors on the `openMainViewController()` function and I'm really new to programming in general - so not yet that knowledgable on where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you made an mistake while copying form the book

Replace your `rootViewController()` with `rootViewController` as this should be a constant rather then a method. like in the `openSignInScreen()`

So your Updated `openMainViewController` will be

```
func openMainViewController() {
        if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarViewController") {
            rootViewController.view.frame =  (self.window?.rootViewController?.view.frame)!
            rootViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            //nice transition between views
            UIView.transition(with: window!, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController }, completion: { completed in //maybe do something here
            })
        }
    }
```

**Note**: For this to work you, you should have a ViewController in the story board with identifier `TabbarViewController`